# Why did my question get opinion-based close votes?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

So I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74370984/13629335) today and it surprisingly got [votes to close](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) it. I do understand where they're coming from; it asks for an opinion, but a qualified one. And Stack Overflow is full of qualified opinions which makes this site so strong, in my opinion. (pun intended)

Examples you will find with the key phrase

1. *How to use XY properly?*
2. *When to use XY?*
3. *Is XY broken/ill considered*

The help center states that [opinion-based questions are allowed as long as they are constructive](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and also see [Real questions have answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/).

I'm asking myself if the tiny little sentence --*This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.* is not misleading to the actual goal of this site?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your title, but it sounds like you're asking if users should wait to close questions as opinion-based after some time? if so, that's incorrect; one should always vote on the question immediately, as it is in the state when they see it. If you mean something else, please clarify

Comment: @TylerH It asks for a guideline, but more to this specific question and if I do understand something fundametally wrong on close votes. It is not about a count down, no.

Comment: Hm I don't see how 2. when to use XY is ever going to lead to an on-topic question that is not drenched in personal opinions. If you see such a question, it might be a very old question or it simply slipped through. 1. how to use is probably going to be more in the "needs more focus" territory, but there can be exceptions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I mean...I don't even see an opinion in your question.

What I see is that you're asking a question, backed with experience and evidence, to determine if using a specific feature makes sense to do.

So I personally wouldn't consider this an opinionated question.  Maybe it's something to do with the title and a bit of phrasing.

Instead of asking if this is a bad practice or not in the title, omit that entirely.

Instead of this text block:

> So my question is, should I avoid this practice at all? Only with caution ? Or am I doing something wrong by using this feature ? Because if you think about, nearly all tkinters dialog windows are using this feature and I've never read about this behavior before.

Reword it to something like this to be more direct and objective:

> Am I doing something wrong by using this feature ? Because if you think about, nearly all tkinters dialog windows are using this feature and I've never read about this behavior before.

Comment: Yes, maybe I should have need to phrase it in a way that doesn't look like I want a discussion on it.

Comment: I know nothing about the topic at all. Opinion-based question or not, the answer doesn't seem to rely much on opinion but experience, logic, and relevant rules for the language to address the problem the question is concerned with. Part of the reason opinion-based questions aren't allowed is because they can be difficult to answer due to being unclear or because they lead to poor answers. This doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @JohnPolo It is usually the topic where I do answer questions. But when I'm asking a question about it, I'll reach out for a handful of people that are incredibly skilled in that matter and mostly authors of at least one of the widgets of tkinter or even core developer. Fortunately they are active on this site and patient enough to deal with me.

Answer (score 2):

I am one of the close voters (I saw the question in the CV queue). I voted to close it as opinion-based because the questions you asked:

> - Is tkwait wait_variable/wait_window/wait_visibility considered bad practice or even broken?
> - should I avoid this practice at all? Only with caution ?
> - Or am I doing something wrong by using this feature ?

are opinion-based questions. "Should I" almost *always* is an opinion-based ask... "should" according to whom? Two different people can answer yes and no and both be "right" based on their opinions or experiences.

The one aspect that might not be opinion-based is "is it broken", but given that you mention "*if you think about, nearly all tkinters dialog windows are using this feature and I've never read about this behavior before*" makes it seem highly unlikely that the feature is broken, and much more likely that you have misunderstood something.

The answer seems to back up this latter option as the more likely one since it describes how to avoid the issue you occur (meaning, to me, it's not broken, just misunderstood).

*N.B. I don't know Python or tkinter*

Comment: If those were stand-alone questions, I could agree with your rationale.  But in context, I find it very hard to see how you leapt to the conclusion that this question *must* be opinion-based.  Despite not knowing the language or library in use, there was a lot to be said about what the OP tried and observed, and what their particular question/reservation was about using this.  Maybe it really *was* the way it was phrased...

Comment: @Makoto I am not sure what you mean by "must be". I think the question has a good chance of being edited by OP to not be opinion-based. But until then the appropriate action is to VTC as opinion-based. Sometimes other users can edit questions so that they are no longer opinion-based, and I do this quite regularly. In this case, I think action by OP is needed to make that clarification/edit.

Comment: Fine, I'll edit the question with the suggestions I floated   It's not like this particular question in the heat of the moment was *so* bad that VTC was an easy priority choice over editing it out to see if it was still VTC, but everyone works on the site differently.

Comment: @Makoto I did not changed it yet for the scope of this (Meta-)question. But thanks :D

Comment: @Makoto Again, I don't know what you mean by "_so_ bad" It met the threshold for opinion-based, so I voted to close it as opinion-based. There aren't different levels of closure for whether something is "sort of opinion-based" vs "omg so extremely opinion-based", etc. If you feel confident enough in the language and technologies to edit the question, that's good, but it's not a _requirement_ for users to do that... it's OP's responsibility to ensure a question is clear, objective, etc. That's what the primarily opinion-based banner says when a question is closed as such.

Comment: As it stands, I don't think the remaining question solves the problems, just shifts them a bit. "*Am I doing something wrong by using this feature?*" doesn't specify what the problem is that OP thinks they're having. We can guess they expect some different behavior, but the question "am I doing something wrong by using this feature" doesn't really address that assumption accurately.

Comment: @TylerH, I respectfully disagree with `"Should I" almost always is an opinion-based ask... "should" according to whom?` Very often for a given third-party library, it is simply: *"according to the standardized way to do it, as documented in the documentation of the library"* and so it's not opinion-based.

Comment: I think one issue here that is generally mistreated is that the mere presence of an opinion does not necessarily mean that the question fits the criteria for closure as opinion based. Expert opinion which cites experience, references official documentation, or provides factual analysis should be encouraged.

Comment: @basj if OP is asking for what an authoritative spec says, that's OK. That's not what OP asked for here. And, btw, often people ask _why_ a spec or authoritative reference is the way it is; such questions are also opinion-based.

Comment: @TravisJ It is not really the same thing when someone asks for context-based suggestions; if someone provides a context in which an otherwise opinionated question would typically be answered the same way every time, that's one thing, and arguably fine. But again, that's not what OP did here. Open-ended "should I do X" questions don't offer that kind of contextual opportunity for all answerers to base their response on the same set of circumstances or constraints.

Comment: @TylerH - I don't think it's fair to minimize the question we are looking at here to simply "should I do X". There is a background, a code example, official documentation cited, and some reasoning for the question of whether there are issues with using that feature in those circumstances. In other words, it does look like there is context here. As features age, we will need experts with experience in long running features sharing with the community problems they have encountered while using them. This helps everyone.